# Preciso de ajuda para criar duas tabelas com estrutura de decisão em PHP

Tags: php

Criar uma aplicação em PHP que verifique palavra por palavra do array abaixo se o total de letras é impar ou par.

Para mostrar o resultado. montar uma página HTML básica com duas tabelas: Uma com as palavras de total de letras ímpares e outra com o total de letras pares, seguida do total das letras.

```
$valores = [ 'estudar', 'educação', 'esforço', 'persistência',
             'dedicação', 'crescimento', 'evolução', 'sabedoria',
             'trabalho', 'entusiasmo', 'alegria', 'vitoria',
             'sucesso', 'profissão', 'conhecimento', 'vida' ];
```

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque parece ser sobre um exercício de lógica o qual não demonstrou ter havido esforço por parte do autor dada a ausência de uma implementação preliminar.

Comment: Isso não é uma dúvida, isso é um enunciado. Tente começar o seu trabalho, conforme as dúvidas forem aparecendo você pode criar perguntas aqui no site para então podermos te ajudar. Aproveita e faça um [tour] pelo site e veja o guia [ask].

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa, se sim, que tal postar o que tentou e se deu algum erro dai sim pode ter uma ajuda mais assertiva.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro passo é pegar o tamanho da palavra com a função [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php), feito isso verifique se o tamanho da palavra retorna ou não o resto da divisão(`$tamanho % 2 == 0`).

Agora defina um array com a seguinte estrutura:

```
$resultado = array('impares' => '', 'total_impares' => 0, 'pares' => '', 'total_pares' => 0);
```

Caso o resto da divisão seja zero então ele é par, adicione essa palavra na chave `$resultado['pares']` e incremente o contador dos pares `$resultado['total_pares'], se o resto for um faça o mesmo processo so que dessa vez nas impares.

Com array formatado, faça dois `foreach()` nas tabelas.

<sub>Obs: outra forma de calcular o total seria usar [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) nas chaves impares/pares e atribuir o valor em `total_impar/par` após o foreach que faz a 'separação'</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Apesar disso ser um exercício de lógica o qual, até o presente momento, aparentemente não teve esforço por parte do autor demonstrado, gostaria de deixar minha contribuição mesmo assim.

A solução é tão simples que, à parte do array de entrada, resolve-se com apenas duas linhas:

```
$words = [ 'estudar', 'educação', 'esforço', 'persistência',
           'dedicação', 'crescimento', 'evolução', 'sabedoria',
           'trabalho', 'entusiasmo', 'alegria', 'vitoria',
           'sucesso', 'profissão', 'conhecimento', 'vida' ];

$odd = array_filter( $words, function( $word ) { return ( strlen( $word ) % 2 == 0 ); } );

$even = array_diff( $words, $odd );
```

Os arrays **$odd** e **$even** resultantes contém, respectivamente:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => string 'educação' (length=10)
  2 => string 'esforço' (length=8)
  6 => string 'evolução' (length=10)
  8 => string 'trabalho' (length=8)
  9 => string 'entusiasmo' (length=10)
  13 => string 'profissão' (length=10)
  14 => string 'conhecimento' (length=12)
  15 => string 'vida' (length=4)

array (size=8)
  0 => string 'estudar' (length=7)
  3 => string 'persistência' (length=13)
  4 => string 'dedicação' (length=11)
  5 => string 'crescimento' (length=11)
  7 => string 'sabedoria' (length=9)
  10 => string 'alegria' (length=7)
  11 => string 'vitoria' (length=7)
  12 => string 'sucesso' (length=7)
```

Ao contrário da indicação do amigo @perdeu, usar [mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/mb_strlen), nesse caso, resulta em falsos-positivos pois faz com os acentos das palavras sejam considerados como comprimentos adicionais.

Leituras recomendada:

- [strlen()](http://www.php.net/strlen)
- [mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/mb_strlen)
- [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/array_filter)
- [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/array_diff)

Comment: +1 pela resposta mais eleborada. Obrigado pela correção tbm. Fiz um teste [aqui](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6hvk-x0g9) com o `strlen` a palavra `aça` ele cai na categoria dos pares, quando vc usa `mb_strlen` e passa o encondig da string ele cai nos impares como esperado.

Comment: Até hoje eu não tenho bem certeza da usabilidade de mb_strlen().